# Docusign document URL links to blank template

Tags: docusignapi

I have code that creates an envelope from a template created on Docusign Admin.  When this envelope is sent via email, the fields on the template are properly filled in to be signed.  However, when using the endpoint /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient, the fields and signing buttons are gone, and all that remains is a blank pdf.  The parameters are

```
"authenticationMethod" => "None",
"userName" => $request->name,
"email" => $request->email,
"recipientId" => 1,
"returnUrl" => $request->returnURL
```

Am I missing something in the payload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `clientUserId` which is required for embedded signing.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response, however it has changed the response to say 
```"errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT",
        "message": "The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope."
```
The documentation says that it is a sender created value, so what do i put in there to properly identify a recipient?

Comment: You are using a template? when creating this envelope? I don't know since I don't see your code, how do you create the envelope? if you are using a template - you need to specify roles.

Comment: to create the envelope i'm using the ```/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes``` endpoint, and there is only one role, the signer, which is assigned using their name, email address and the recipientId which defaults to 1

Comment: but do you pass a templateId in the call?

Comment: Yes i do here is the code:
```"status" => "sent",
                "templateId" => "111-111-11", //dud id
                "emailSubject" => "",
                "emailBlurb" => "",
                "templateRoles" => [[
                    "roleName" => "Signee",
                    "recipientId" => 1,
                    "email" => $request->docusignEmail,
                    "name" => $request->docusignName,
                    "tabs" => []
```
the tabs are filled with data to be submitted to the template